# How to run multiple dokuwiki instances on debian with lighttpd

Tags: debian, lighttpd, wiki

I installed dokuwiki using the guide [here](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:debian). Everything was very easy and works great. Now I want to run a second wiki on the same server. I have read enough that I think I could hack it together by copying files around and editing config files but I was hoping there was a recommended way.

Comment: I believe you want to create a DokuWiki [Farm](https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:farm). Have a look and see if this helps.